# iPhone - Apple default sample code missing some vars?

Tags: iphone, properties, class-design, instance-variables

In XCode 4, when you create a new View-base-application project, here is the .h of the AppDelegate :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class TestAppleProjectViewController;

@interface TestAppleProjectAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet TestAppleProjectViewController *viewController;

@end
```

And some items on the .m :

```
@implementation TestAppleProjectAppDelegate

@synthesize window=_window;
@synthesize viewController=_viewController;

    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    { 
        self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
        return YES;
    }
```

I can see properties without vars...
I can see synthesize with var names that does not exist in the class...
I can see calls to those properties....

But... Where are the vars ?
Why such a code is working ?
Are there no more need to define vars into the class ? Are properties enough ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact when you declare a var as a property, you don't have to declare it again as var. The previous comportment where we had to declare it again was a bug in the previous versions of Xcode. And now it's corrected.

It's just an habit to take, less code duplicate and it's good. (By default it's creating ah hidden var with the same name beginning by "_").

Comment: Uhhh... If only they could have removed the need to write the default synthesize line too...

Comment: The old behaviour wasn't a "bug", nor does it have anything to do with Xcode---it was a feature of the [legacy Objective-C runtime](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtVersionsPlatforms.html). Automatic ivar generation is a feature of the modern runtime, and is only available on platforms that support it (iPhone & 64-bit 10.5+).

Comment: The synthesize is not the same! Property is for the compiler to know that there is a var with accessors. Synthesize is to generate these accessors. You can use @property without @synthesize and write yourself you assessors. Or simply declare the synthesize like: @synthesize window;

Comment: Important note. If you do not add the var, the gdb debugger will not be able to tell you the value of the var at breakpoints.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about this... I think when you write `@synthesize prop=_var` it will automatically create a private instance variable named _var for the property prop.